# customize react-native navigator swipe

Tags: navigation, react-native

Is it possible/how can you change the swipe back functionality of the react-native Navigator?  Swipe back pops a route, what if I want it to popToTop or not do anything, or maybe...just maybe jumpTo a certain route?

Comment: I no longer need this answered, I found another (better/more proper) way, but is it possible?????  of course it is...I'll give a dollar to whoever answers this

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is! The UI explorer does a good job at showing what is built in. [UIExplorer Navigator](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator) and checkout the [UI explorer in action here](http://www.reactnative.com/uiexplorer/).

I followed very similarly the examples given in the explorer and didn't have any problems.

if you want to completely customize the transition i would say to look over the source where the transition animations are and mimic them to fit your needs. Brent Vatne gave a talk at reactive 2015 on the second day, that talks about animations and performance. He gave some hints about this particular topic.